# How to save response ID in Google Form to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using a Google Form and it's response automatically saves to a spreadsheet.
I can get response ID in a script with the form:

```
function submitForm2(e) {
  Logger.log(e.response.getId());
}
```

I want to save the id to the spreadsheet.
How can I do for that?

Comment: Best and cleanest solution I have found so far => https://ctrlq.org/code/20540-edit-form-response-spreadsheet-url.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like:

```
function submitForm2(e) {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('----------').getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
   sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), --).setValue(e.response.getId()); 
}
```

Insert the ID of the target Spreadsheet and the column index of the first empty column in the sheet.